# Blank admin login page with Security titled empty field set

Tags: magento2, security, admin-panel, magento2.2.9

We have a working Magento 2.2.9 installation in production. Everything was fine and working and no one touched the code or the settings for weeks now. Today we suddenly could not log in to admin panel any more. Instead of the login screen this is what we saw when trying to access the login page:

[image]

The markup is this:

```
<div class="entry-edit form-inline">
        <fieldset class="fieldset admin__fieldset " id="mp_tfa_security">
                <legend class="admin__legend legend">
            <span>Security</span>
        </legend><br />
<div class="messages">
        </div>
    <div class="admin__field field field-mp_tfa_secret_temp  no-label"  
data-ui-id="adminhtml-system-account-edit-form-fieldset-element-form-field-mp-tfa-
secret-temp" >
                            <div class="admin__field-control control">
```

We tried it from two different computers from completely different external IP addresses and the result was the same. After some time spent googleing and not finding anything about such issue, <strike>**I tried to access it from a private window and it worked**. So clearly, as soon as I clear the website data from the browser it will work from the non-private window as well (Option+Cmd+R does not help), but I'm wondering what could cause this?</strike>

Only the login screen works from private mode. After login I still get this white page with Security title. Tried with Safari and Chrome. Results are the same so it's not related to browser cache or previously saved website data.

Any ideas?

Comment: I still don't know what caused this so I'm not posting this as an answer just as a workaround. I could log in with a new admin account I created with Magento CLI. Then I changed the original admin's password from the new admin account and the old admin account was also able to log in afterwards.

Comment: Open app/bootstrap.php around line 14 change #ini_set('display_errors', 1); to ini_set('display_errors', 1); save and upload and refresh the page to see if any errors display on the page itself

Comment: I tried adding ini_set('display_errors', 1); to index.php when the problem was still present but nothing changed. Since it's gone now, it's too late to try it. There was nothing relevant in the logs though.